# Looping through links on a page and clicking each one despite rerenders

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function to save all the link elements with page numbers to an array and then use javascript to click to the next page after a certain time interval. However, everytime the function runs it will click the first page, cause a rerender of the page and my array now becomes undefined. I need a way to somehow overcome this and I am not sure how to do this. Here is my code:

```
const pages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[_ngcontent-c128]'));
for(i = 0; i < pages.length; i++){
    let newPages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[_ngcontent-c128]'));
    newPages[i].click();
}
```

Comment: make it json string and store it in the `window.name` attribute, as long as the tab isn't closed, the data should remain. This also allows you to browse away from the domain and return.

Comment: Everytime you click on a link you page is reloaded and you lose your state, try to use window.open(URL, "_blank"); but this will open new tabs/windows in your browser

Comment: @Tschallacka can you share an example? I am unfamiliar with the window attribute

Comment: ... `window.name = JSON.stringify({foobar:'bazbal'});` execute that in console. browse a bit of reddit, then a bit of imgur, then go to youtube and then run `my_saved_properties = JSON.parse(window.name)`  and you see your saved data is there. You might have to restructure your code since dom elements can't be stringified.